# how to fill a vector with objects using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector

I have an assignment where I have to create a vector and fill it with objects. I found this code:

```
Vehicle * v = NULL;
vector<Vehicle*> *highway;
highway = new vector<Vehicle*>;
```

I understand the first line where it creates a pointer named `v` that is empty and points at the object `Vehicle`.

Can you please explain to me how the other 2 lines work and why is it using pointers when creating the vector?

Comment: Why do you need pointers at all? Especially `vector<Vehicle *> * highway;` looks weird.

Comment: No idea thats why i'm asking.. this is some code a friend sent me and woks just fine but i dont want to use it without realising how it works

Comment: A vector is a collection of types that lay together. You can instantiate a vector with ' vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3} ' and it will fill automatically fill the vector with 1-3. Pls. read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ for an example on how to add to a vector.

Comment: i understand that what i am asking is how does this particular code works step by step

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brief explanation line by line:

```
Vehicle * v = NULL;
```

define a pointer `v` of type `Vehicle` and initialize it to `NULL`.

```
vector<Vehicle*> *highway;
```

define a pointer `highway` of type `vector<Vehicle*>`.

```
highway = new vector<Vehicle*>;
```

dynamically allocate `vector<Vehicle*>` and assign it to vector `highway`.

Have a look at [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and make sure you understand why the last two lines doesn't make much sense.

### Now, to answer the question:

> How to fill a vector with objects using pointers?

To fill the dynamically allocated vector, you could write:

```
highway->push_back(Vehicle_Element);
```

Answer (score 0):

First line: You create a pointer of type "Vehicle". It is not pointing at a object, because it is NULL. It points to nothing. You have to create an object like:

```
Vehicle* v = new Vehicle;
```

Second line: Same construction like the first line: You create a pointer of type "vector". Now its not pointing anywhere. If you create (see third line) it than you have a pointer to a vector which has pointers to Vehicle objects.

Third line: With this line you create the vector pointer.